# Applying :focus pseudo-class on an element

Tags: html, css

Here, I want to edit some attributes of my label when there is a focus event on input field so,

But it is not working, when the input field gains focus there is no change in label element what should i do both of the below methods are not working for me.

I am writing it as,

```
  .input-field:focus + .input-label{
     background : black;
   }
   or
  .input-field:focus .input-label{
     background : black;
   }
```

Both the methods are not working for me.

Comment: Do u want the background black for input box on focus? or plz send me the html code

Comment: Please provide your HTML code.

Comment: Your first code would only work if your label is a sibling of your input and comes *after* the input field. The other one would only work if the label is a child of your input field which is not possible

Comment: Show your html code because there are a lot of way according to html code

Comment: Using my magic glass, I guess you want to change your element style when ANOTHER element gains focus? If yes, you may need some Javascript here

Comment: thanks you guys especially Tim Gerhard for your suggestion it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `:focus-within` pseudo selector to achieve the desired functionality. This selector works if element receives focus or *contains* another element which receives focus.

```css
.container:focus-within label{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

You can read more about this selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within). Note, that this method is not supported in IE, but who cares...